# PUSH уведомления без app

Tags: android, google-pay

Можно ли отсылать PUSH уведомления без приложения на Andoid?
Я занимаюсь созданием карты лояльности и использую Google Pay, с помощью сервисов Google Pay API невозможно отправить PUSH уведомление, которое нужно вам.
В сервисе OSMI cards создается карта в google pay и через нее посылаются push. Как это реализовать?

Comment: пуш должен кто-то обработать перед показом, поэтому маловероятно что вы сможете его показать без приложения

Comment: Нет приложения - нет токена (адреса получателя). Соответственно куда отправлять?

Comment: Можно: SMS называется, отправляется на телефонный номер)